# What will happen to my installed softwares if I migrate to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, migration

Imagine you're using Photoshop, SQL Server, Visual Studio, Winrar, and any other installed software on Windows Vista.

What will happen to them if you upgrade you Windows Vista to Windows 7.

Are they still there? Or it's necessary to reinstall all softwares again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vista to Windows 7 - Upgrading or clean installation?](http://superuser.com/questions/69662/vista-to-windows-7-upgrading-or-clean-installation)

Comment: @Mepher - I'm not sure about the duplicate. That doesn't address the issue of keeping existing applications.

Comment: @ChrisF: I disagree. Accepted answer includes details about the issue: http://superuser.com/questions/69662/vista-to-windows-7-upgrading-or-clean-installation/69667#69667

Comment: Similar but not a true duplicate, same basic issue but not the same intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Step 2 on this [upgrade guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-vista-to-windows-7) from Microsoft:

> When you upgrade to Windows 7, you keep your files, settings, and programs from Windows Vista.

There are some conditions (for example):

> Be sure your computer is running either Service Pack 1 or Service Pack 2 for Windows Vista. For more information, see the Windows Vista service packs webpage on the Microsoft website.

I'd also make sure that all my data was backed up first too.

Comment: Perhaps it should be necessary to do a clean install, but it will take hours to install all legacy softwares again

Answer (score 0):

Easy one run the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx)
"It scans your PC for potential issues with your hardware, devices, and installed programs, and recommends what to do before you upgrade."

It will tell you what programs will work with Windows 7 and which will not. Also the [Tutorial](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-vista-to-windows-7) 'ChrisF' Posted is a good start.

Vista & Windows 7 use essentially the same kernel, most Vista software runs fine in Win7. The MS Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor will tell you about any software, Drivers, and/or Hardware that will not function correctly with Windows 7, or needs patching/upgrades.

"If your PC can run Windows Vista, it can probably run Windows 7, but it's still a good idea to use the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor. Use the [Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/default.aspx) to see if your hardware and software will work with Windows 7."

Comment: Hi Bear, I'm afraid it's not about what is compatible, but if my already installed softwares will keep working without reinstalling all of them.

Comment: Junior - if it is compatible it will keep working without reinstalling that it what the Upgrade Advisor will tell you.

Comment: Edit: (Updated & Extended for Clarification)