# Should I upgrade my Windows Vista to Windows 7 or wipe/format/install Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vista to Windows 7 - Upgrading or clean installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/69662/vista-to-windows-7-upgrading-or-clean-installation)

Should I upgrade my Windows Vista to Windows 7 or wipe/format/install Windows 7?

I have a Dell Precision T3400 workstation that came with Windows Vista and a few months later Dell shipped me a Windows 7 upgrade (for free). I have yet to upgrade it and as it's inconvenient to backup/format/install Windows 7. The question is, should I just upgrade directly without a format?

I don't know if this is a proper question, or if it even can be one, but I need details on experiences with upgrading. I have *never* done this before, but Win Vista --> Win 7 doesn't seem like an upgrade with lots of pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Well the upgrade would work but it is a better approach do do a reinstall since you get rid of all the unneeded clutter.

I would go with a reinstall if I where you but an upgrade would serve you well too.

So if it is just a matter of using the free upgrade or buying a new disk for a fresh install then upgrade otherwise format

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your end goal.

If your end goal is a perfect install, do a clean install.  Windows 7 allows you to do a clean install while leaving a copy of your old files on the drive. (It can also completely wipe the drive)

If your goal is a quick install, go the upgrade path, but only if you feel that your installation of Vista is not overly corrupted. If you think that is corrupted, do a clean install as it may cause issues later if you upgrade a corrupt OS. Remember to update your drivers after install!

Either option is fine, but I usually do a clean install when I install Windows 7 (or any other OS)

Comment: I'm going with the clean install as what I'm after is longevity and when is it a better time to do a clean install than when installing a new O/S.

Answer (score 0):

Do an inplace upgrade. A lot more convenient if you have got data there. If you haven’t, you should do a clean install.